How to add a thumbnail to a Shopify slider section
I'm working on a Shopify store where we use several GIF images to showcase product features. However, I've noticed that GIFs can take a while to load, especially on slower connections, which impacts the user experience.
I want to implement a solution where a static thumbnail image is displayed before the GIF fully loads. Ideally, this would work as follows:

A static image (e.g., the first frame of the GIF) is shown initially.
The GIF loads in the background.
Once the GIF is fully loaded, it replaces the static image.

I'm not sure how to achieve this in Shopify. Here are my questions:

Is there a built-in Shopify feature or app that can handle this?
If not, what would be the best way to implement this using HTML, CSS, and JavaScript?
How can I ensure this works with Shopify's image CDN and lazy loading features?
Are there any performance considerations I should keep in mind?

Any guidance or code examples would be greatly appreciated!
